# 3 dimensional vector representation with Hue color data

Tags: plotting, vector

I am trying to represent 3-dimensional vectors in a 3-dimensional space. 
In my field, there is a common color coding (color wheel) as in the picture.

For (vx,vy,vz) vectors:
(0,0,1) is white,
(0,0,-1) is black,
(vx,vy,0) is a Hue coloring. 
As vz changes from -1 to 1, we may need to adjust the saturation and brightness for Hue function, but I am stuck how to show it. How can I make a VectorColorFunction for ListVectorPlot3D with such color-wheel?

[image]
[image]

For example, the third image is a failed one with

```
g = VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, {z, -6, 6}, 
  VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", VectorPoints -> 15, 
  VectorColorFunction -> 
   Function[{x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, n}, 
    ColorData["Rainbow"][Arg[vx + I vy]]], AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
  VectorScale -> {0.15, Scaled[0.5]}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 4^2 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 5^2]]
```

: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's define a helper function which maps from unit vectors to our desired colors:

```
HSLFromUnitVector = Function[{x, y, z}, 
  Hue[Mod[Arg[x + I*y]/(2 \[Pi]), 1], Min[1, 1 - z], (1 + z)/2]
]
```

I named it `HSL...` based on the [HSL color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) which it shares a close resemblance with. It's quite certainly not a 100% accurate implementation of it, but it should give you the general idea and, with a bit of time could be perfected if needed.

Then we can use it to get the coloring in the vector field plot:

```
VectorPlot3D[{x, y, z}, {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, {z, -6, 6}, 
  VectorStyle -> "Arrow3D", VectorPoints -> 15, 
  VectorColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, vx, vy, vz, n}, 
    HSLFromUnitVector @@ Normalize[{vx, vy, vz}]
  ], 
  VectorColorFunctionScaling -> False, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}, 
  VectorScale -> {0.15, Scaled[0.5]}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 4^2 < x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 5^2]
]
```

[image: HSL color vector field plot]

Notice the added `VectorColorFuncctionScaling->False` which makes sure that our `VctorColorFunction` gets the original `{vx,vy,vz}` values and not rescaled values, which would sabotage our color scheme.

The effect is easier to see on a sphere:

```
SphericalPlot3D[1, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {\[Phi], -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, HSLFromUnitVector @@ {x, y, z}]
]
```

[image: HSL coloring on sphere]

Comment: Thank you very much. It looks awesome. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uccq8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uccq8.png)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/77843)

Comment: @emrah Thanks for the feedback! Glad that it works for you!